# Riemannian Fisher-Rao metric and orthogonal parameter space.

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a family of probability distributions  $\mathcal{P}$ of random variable $\beta$ which is smoothly  parametrized  by a finite number of real parameters, i.e., $\mathcal{S}=\left\{\mathcal{P}_{\theta}=w(\beta;\theta);\theta \in \mathbb{R}^{n}, \theta=(\theta^{i})\right\}$. The statistical model $\mathcal{S}$ carries the structure of smooth Riemannian manifold $\mathcal{M}$, with respect to which $\theta=(\theta^{i})$ play the role of coordinates of a point $\mathcal{P}_{\theta}\in \mathcal{S}$, and whose metric is defined by the Fisher's information matrix $\mbox{H}=(g_{ij}(\theta))$, where the coefficients of this matrix,  which yields a positive definite metric, are calculated as the expectation of a product involving partial derivatives of the logarithm of the probability density function's (PDF)

\begin{equation*}
g_{ij}(\theta)=\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \displaystyle \frac{\partial^{2}ln \left( w(\beta;\theta)\right)}{\partial \theta^{i} \partial \theta^{j}}w(\beta;\theta)d\beta.
\end{equation*}

How do we neglect the off-diagonal terms $g_{12}$=$g_{21}$?

In other words, is there a mathematical argument, wherein it is possible to consider $g_{12}=g_{21}$=0?

Comment: It's not true that off-diagonal terms in $g_{ij}$ vanish in arbitrary coordinates. However, given a distribution $s\in\mathcal{S}$, we can always choose a particular set of coordinates so that $g_{ij}(s)$ is diagonal. See [Riemann Normal Coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_coordinates), as an example of this.

Comment: Under the hypothesis that the parameter space is orthogonal, would we may neglect the $g_{12}=g_{21}$?

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply this whole integral by the Kronecker delta $\delta^{i}_{j}$. Then, in this way, you will have zero for elements with different indices (off-diagonal elements).